# Angular 4/5 and nginx proxy: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: angular, nginx, proxy

I'm running 2 sites, one in `PHP` and one in `Angular 5` with `nginx` proxy on top. Here's my proxy config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mysite.loc;

    ### php
    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }

    ### angular (ng serve --disable-host-check)
    location /dashboard
    {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }

}
```

Accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8080`, `http://127.0.0.1:4200` works and that `http://mysite.loc` displays what is in the PHP site (from port 8080).

`http://mysite.loc/dashboard` also works but Angular outputs this error on the console:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

I tried serving the site using this:

`ng s --disable-host-check --base-href /dashboard/`

caused an infinite loop loading `sockjs-node` resources

Note that the Angular application is newly-set up and that no special routing exists yet. I figured that the site starting at `/dashboard` confuses Angular's internal routing mechanism.

Anyone knows how to remedy this problem? TIA

Answer (score -1):

I had the same, but having 2 react app in one node with nginx, I could fix it with:
https://serverfault.com/questions/562756/how-to-remove-the-path-with-an-nginx-proxy-pass/562850#562850

You can try modifying your nginx config like:

```
    location /dashboard {
            return 302 /dashboard/;
    }
    location /dashboard/ {
            proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:4200/;               
    }
```